# Update user with new custom attribute C# LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I need update a specific user ldap with new custom attributes. When run throw Exception "Unhandled Exception: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist". My code is:

```
using (var entryRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.com:389/OU=CATALOG,DC=ldap,DC=com", "juan", "juan2016", AuthenticationTypes.Secure)){
    DirectorySearcher user_searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entryRoot);

    user_searcher.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samAccountName={cn1}))"

    user_searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("identification");

    SearchResultCollection result = user_searcher.FindAll();

    DirectoryEntry user_ldap = result[0].GetDirectoryEntry();

    user_ldap.Properties["identification"].Value = identification;

    user_ldap.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you'll need to add the attribute to the user before trying to set it to something...

Comment: Did you add the `identification` attribute to your schema manually? It's not a valid attribute out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the customs attributes in "Active Directory Schema" and assign to user class as optional attribute, after runed my code and successful result